# Read data attribute on jquery autocomplete

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I started with a small script. To do an autocomplete in my Laravel application. Now I want to read the data attribute from the #searchform.

When I already have :)

```
$( "#searchform" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/Ajax/{{ need ID }}/",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
  }
});
```

I need to get the id from an event. Those events are stored in the html of the searchbox

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" type="search" id="searchform" data-event="60618484519" placeholder="Search on name">
```

How can I read the data(event) attribute in my Jquery

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/ ?

Answer (score 0):

> In source you can use `this.element` which refers to the input

```
$( "#searchform" ).autocomplete({
  source: this.element.attr('searchform'),
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
  }
});
```